# How to debug droplets using AppleScript

Tags: debugging, applescript, droplet

Just 3 lines of script to be able to test a droplet application without leaving applescript editor

```
set fich to POSIX file "/Appli/conv2spct.app" as string

 tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Users/yourusername/Desktop/somefile" using application file fich
```

If there are errors in your droplet a display dialog will be opened by the script editor applescript

Comment: Good stuff, but I suggest making it clearer why your code is necessary (Script Editor will launch a stay-open application being developed, but won't keep it open). I suggest explaining just the need for your solution in the question, and moving both solutions into your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pragmatic alternative using `do shell script`, which potentially allows you to specify *multiple* file arguments:

```
do shell script "open -a /Appli/conv2spct.app ~/Desktop/somefile1 ~/Desktop/somefile2"
```

The above paths happen not to need quoting (escaping) for the shell, but when using variables to specify the file paths, it's best to use `quoted form of` (to pass multiple arguments, apply `quoted form of` to *each*):

```
do shell script "open -a " & quoted form of fileappli & " " & quoted form of fileargument
```

Answer (score 1):

The same script with choose file for the 2 elements

```
set fileappli to POSIX path choose file of type {"APPL"} with prompt "Choose a Droplet application to debug"--the droplet for debug

set fileargument to POSIX path choose file --the file argument to pass at droplet 

tell application "Finder" to open fileargument using application file fileappli
```

If there are errors in your droplet a display dialog will be opened by the script editor applescript

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has become simpler since the question was first asked. According to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ProcessDroppedFilesandFolders.html) you can write:

```
open {choose file}
on open theDroppedItems
  ...
end open
```

Run this from within the AppleScript editor and the file you choose will be opened as if it had been dropped onto the compiled script.